# What's the physical meaning of the boundary value problems at resonance?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Many papers deal with the boundary value problems at resonance. But how to understand the problems at resonance? Why do they talk about these kinds problems? What is the physical meaning?